# Jinja2 replace string with '.' joiner

Tags: string, text, replace, jinja2

I search the best method to replace last number of an IP with Jinja2.

I need to replace the last octet of the IP:

```
{% set ip = "192.168.1.1" %}
{% set points == ip.split('.') %}
{{ points | last | replace (points | last , "0") }}
```

Result: `0`
Desired result: `192.168.1.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Python's slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) in order to get all the list elements except the last one with a negative index, then

1. either concatenate a list containing your new element and finally join

   ```
   {{ ("192.168.1.1".split(".")[:-1] + ["0"]) | join(".") }}
   ```
2. or join and then concatenate with a string with your new element

   ```
   {{ "192.168.1.1".split(".")[:-1] | join(".") + ".0" }}
   ```